# How to find the exact error location for a very long SQL query inside a C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have very long SQL queries in C# code and sometimes the error that I get is not clear enough to understand where in the SQL query the error has happened.
Is there any method or trick to find out which line of the SQL query has caused error?

For example I have this block of code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
SqlConnection conn = ...

string my_query =
" select * from [this_is_just_sample_command] ... " +
" select top 1 from [this_is_just_example_command] ... " +
" select top 10 from [hundreds_of_different_commands] ... " +
" select top 100 from [written_just_to_satisfy_the_admin_who_closed_the_already_clear_question] ... " ;

using (SqlCommand my_command = new SqlCommand (my_query, conn))  
{
     my_command .ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and for example I receive this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
> definition.

It can be anywhere in my SQL query. I tried to put some intentional errors in different locations in my SQL query to see if the intended error happens before or after the unknown error. But this trick also didn't help.

My question is NOT about this particular error. I'm trying to find a way to find the location of error trigger in any SQL query.

Any suggestion? Ideally I wish to receive the exact part of the SQL query which has triggered the error.

Comment: *"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."* Can only actually be in one place, your `INSERT`. it's saying that you the number of columns you are trying to `INSERT` doesn't match the number of columns defined in the `INSERT INTO` clause. For example `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Col1) SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM dbo.OtherTable` or `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES('SomeVal');` would both generate the error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.linenumber?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0?

Comment: Though the full exception will tell you the line number of the error as well, which will greatly help you tell where the problem is (assuming you have formatted your SQL, but then, why wouldn't you have?).

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `my_command .ExecuteNonQuery();` and copy the value of `my_query` to SSMS and try it there. As already mentioned, it is most likely an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Don't use long SQL queries to begin with. Extract the code into a stored procedure. Or copy the query string and try to validate/execute it in SSMS or Azure Data Studio

Comment: The latest edit, which hides the type of statements you are doing, is really not helping us help you. At least before we "knew" what type of statements you were doing. Now you could be doing *anything*. This has gone from us having good suspicions of the problem to lacking any debugging details. `do this` and `do that` are ***not*** valid T-SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu
As I wrote, that block of code was just to symbolize a very long long query. I edited my post to reduce ambiguities. There's no single insert. There are many many many table modifications of all forms.

Comment: Thank you @Filburt. It's not possible. Because the query itself is make of string modifications which are dependent on my previous C# code lines. That instance of SQL query would result error in SSMS.

Comment: Short answer - there is no generic answer to this. SQL errors aren't specific enough to pinpoint where the bug is in C#.

Comment: @Iraj If your code up to the breakpoint ran, why should executing the generated SQL query fail? As suggested, breaking up the query into individual statements would be a cleaner and easier to maintain way.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this sort of problem for years; I help maintain an app with many queries of staggering size.

My *only* surefire solution to finding these sorts of problems is SQL Server Management Studio. Often, just pasting the text of the query into a SSMS query box highlights the problem.  Sometimes running the query is also necessary to identify the problem.

In the case of parameterized queries, SSMS accepts those.

In the case of queries constructed with code, I find I have to capture the constructed query and dump it somewhere (in my case into an HTML comment in debug mode).

This is, no doubt, a pain in the you-know-what. I usually try to refactor big queries to make them easier to reason about and debug. I'm fairly hard-nosed about query formatting to make them readable, even embedded in code.

Using stored code?  It happens that my org's app deployment procedures make it hard and unreliable to roll out updates to DBMS objects like stored procedures. So big parameterized / prepared statements are the way to go.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just don't understand the topic of stored code here. Stored procedure are for inside the pure SQL query and when you right query in C# it's not of use. And C# itself doesn't have such a thing as far as I know. Sorry for naive question.

Comment: A stored procedure / function is SQL-style code in SQL Server. You can run it with queries like `EXEC [dbo]MyProcedure param1 param2 param3;` Search for `sql server stored procedure in c# ~example` to find some tutorial examples.